# generating new line for each loop bash

Tags: bash, loops, unix, for-loop

I have this problem about bash output i need to write code that would output:

```
1
22
333
```

using loops so far i have this code:

```
First loop....
for ((i=1; i<=1; i=i+1))
do
    echo $i
done
#Second loop....
for ((i=1; i<=2; i++))
do

for ((j=2; j<=2; j++))
do
    echo -n $j

done
done
#Third loop.....
for ((i=1; i<=2; i++))
do

for ((j=2; j<=2; j++))
do
    echo -e $j

done
done
```

Problem is it outputs third loop inside the second like

```
1 
223 
33
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you mixing all these different types of `echo`?

Comment: Why not simply use arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

A simple nested for loop is be sufficient to do what you want:

CODE:

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
    for((j=1; j<=$i; j++)) 
    do
        echo -n $i
    done
    echo
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Answer (score 0):

Just output the newline after the first loop ends:

```
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)) ; do
    for ((j=1; j<=i; j++)) ; do
        echo -n $i
    done
    echo
done
```

Note that in Perl, you can hide the inner loop in the repetition operator `x`:

```
perl -le 'print $_ x $_ for 1 .. 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try two nested `for` loops with interactive start and finish values read from *STDIN* like so:

```
# To make it more interactive
echo -n 'Enter start value: '
read START
echo -n 'Enter finish value: '
read FINISH

# Two nested for loops
for ((I=$START; I<=FINISH; I++))
do
    for ((J=$START; J<=$I; J++))
    do
        echo -n $I
    done
    echo
done
```